# How to encode different size of feature vectors in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, weka, text-classification

I work on classifying some reviews (paragraphs) consists of multiple sentences. I classified them with bag-of-word features in Weka via libSVM. However, I had another idea which I don't know how to implement :

I thought creating syntactical and shallow-semantics based features per sentence in the reviews is worth to try. However, I couldn't find any way to encode those features sequentially, since a paragraph's sentence size varies. The reason that I wanted to keep those features in an order is that the order of sentence features may give a better clue for classification. For example, if I have two instances P1 (with 3 sentences) and P2 (2 sentences), I would have a space like that (assume each sentence has one binary feature as a or b):

P1 -> a b b /classX
P2 -> b a /classY

So, my question is that whether I can implement that classification of different feature sizes in feature space or not? If yes, is there any kind of classifier that I can use in Weka, scikit-learn or Mallet? I would appreciate any responses.

Thanks

Comment: Feature engineering is the art of translating your ideas into fixed length vectors :)

Comment: :) yeah, seems that I have to learn it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of the implementation, an SVM with the standard kernels (linear, poly, RBF) requires fixed-length feature vectors. You can encode any information in those feature vectors by encoding as booleans; e.g. collect all syntactical/semantic features that occur in your corpus, then introduce booleans that represent that "feature such and such occurred in this document". If it's important to capture the fact that these features occur in multiple sentences, count them and use put the frequency in the feature vector (but be sure to normalize your frequencies by document length, as SVMs are not scale-invariant).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I forgot about this post sorry; I had to create those boolean and frequency based features without normalization. I will compare my results by applying normalization as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are classifying textual data, I would suggest looking at "Rational Kernels" which are made on weighted finite transducers for classifying natural language texts. Rational Kernels can be applied on varied length vectors and are already implemented as an open source project (OpenFST).

Answer (score -3):

It is the library's problem, since SVM itself does not require fixed-length feature vectors, it only need a kernel function, if you can provide a kernel function with varied length vector, it should be OK for SVM